# Roles - Identity Server 4

Tags: roles, identityserver4, claims

I have a project done with Asp.Net Core 2.0 API, Identity Server and WPF app. 
I am able to access the API from WPF after I login in.

Now I am trying to implement roles so I can be able to authorize just certain users to access the API.

In Config.cs I am declaring my Client and add to the scope :

```
  new Client
            {
             AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    "fiver_auth_api",
                    "role"
                },
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken=true
           }
```

Declaring TestUser:

```
  return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "", Username = "", Password = "",
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "AliceSmith@email.com"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "openid offline_access fiver_auth_api")
                }
            }
       }
```

And in the controller I am using :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Why I don`t get the user claims in the token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For who is interested there is how I fixed it:
In your configuration file add a list for your roles:

```
new ApiResource
 (
   "fiver_auth_api", 
   "Fiver.Security.AuthServer.Api", 
    new List<string> {"role"} <--- Add this line to your API
  )
```